# Rmarkdown pdf "error opening file:2" R-shiny

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, r-markdown

I want to create a pdf document as a report for my application using Rmarkdown files.
I have 2 problems here.

First: the pdf file is created  but it's empty, because I get this error:

```
Output created: report.pdf
Error opening file: 2
Error reading: 9
```

Here is the simplified code of my shiny app:

**Server.R**

```
 library(shiny)
 library(drsmooth)
 library(shinyBS)
 library(knitr)
 library(rmarkdown)

 shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
         ...get input from user...

output$report <- downloadHandler(
filename <- 'report.pdf',
content <- function(file) {
  rmarkdown::render('report.Rmd')
},

contentType = 'application/pdf')
})

output$tb <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(data1())) {
tags$p(tags$h1("Welcome!")
} else {
 tabsetPanel(
 tabPanel("Preliminary stats")
 tabPanel("Report",downloadButton('report'))
}
```

**report.Rmd** (It is just the template given by R studio so the input part of my app shoudn't matter)

````
---
title: "REPORT"
author: " "
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: pdf_document
---

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r}
summary(cars)

```

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

When I click on the download button I can see from the output in Rstudio console that the output report.pdf is created, but it's empty and the download doesn't start. Any ideas?

Second question is relevant only if you can help me in fixing this. 
Can I use Rshiny objects created within the app in a Rmarkdown file to produce a pdf report(not html)?

For any further information or clarification let me know.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? If windows have you installed Latex? [MiKTex](http://miktex.org/download) You have to install "complete" installation. If you can generate pdf by using rmarkdown you probably have installed latex.

Comment: I'm under a unix system and yes latex is installed correctly.

Comment: Have you checked this example[Knitr Example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/download-knitr-reports.html). There is solution for read and write permissions if that's the case.

Comment: That example solved my problem and as you correctly said it was a permission problem. Thanks @MikaelJumppanen.